# How to import swift class as a custom class for view controller in objective c

Tags: ios, swift, class, uiviewcontroller, import

I have imported chart library(swift file) into my objective C project.Then i have created a new file in swift called BarchartViewController. Now i want to set BarchartViewController as a custom class for view controller.But BarchartViewController is not shown in the Custom class.

How to set the Swift file as a Custom Class in Objective c project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From chart documentation:

> In order to correctly compile:
>
> Drag the Charts.xcodeproj to your project
>
> Go to your target's settings, hit the "+" under the "Embedded
>   Binaries" section, and select the Charts.framework
>
> Temporary workaround: Xcode 6.3.1 has a bug, where you have to build
>   your project once before actually writing the @import line. So hit
>   "Build" now!
>
> @import Charts
>
> When using Swift in an ObjC project:
>
> You need to import your Bridging Header. Usually it is
>   "YourProject-Swift.h", so in ChartsDemo it's "ChartsDemo-Swift.h". Do
>   not try to actually include "ChartsDemo-Swift.h" in your project :-)
>
> Under "Build Options", mark "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code"

Comment: i Want Use the array which is used in Swift class in my objective c class.How to import and use the values in my objective c class?